# But WHY PetaPoco chose to convert Guid to string?

Tags: orm, petapoco

When I look PetaPoco [ Micro ORM ] code I see that

```
else if (t == typeof(Guid))
{
                    p.Value = item.ToString();
                    p.DbType = DbType.String;
                    p.Size = 40;
}
```

Why PetaPoco makes this decision? Choose to write guid as string instead of binary?

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier to query your database from outside your application if the GUID are mapped to strings.